# Artifacts into UE5.1.1

Tags: .fbx, unreal-engine

I'm trying to import a FBX file into Unreal Engine 5.1.1 and appear this artifacts on the mesh of the model, I check out the face orientations and recalculate the normals otside and nothing change, does anyone know what happend?
[image]

[image]